# WP_Query - posts_per_page parameter not working?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

So the setup is working fine, however I tried to limit the number of titles shown but nothing is working. What am I missing? So it should be limited to 10 or 5 titles.

I tried everything I could think of but for some reason it is not taking the limit in account.

```php
<?php 
$meta_query = array();

$args_booking = array(
    'post_type'      => 'booking',
    'post_status'    => array('publish', 'pending', 'canceled'),
    'nopaging'       => 'false',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby'        => array(
        'menu_order' => 'ASC',
        'date'       => 'DESC',
    ),
);

$meta_query[] = array(
    'key'     => GOLO_METABOX_PREFIX. 'booking_item_author',
    'value'   => $user_id,
    'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
    'compare' => '=',
);

$args_booking['meta_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    $meta_query
);

//$data_booking = new WP_Query($args_booking);
//$total_post = $data_booking->found_posts;

if( count($results) > 0 ){//if( $total_post > 0 ){

    ?>

    <ul class="listing-detail custom-scrollbar">
        <?php foreach ($results as $r):?>
        <?php
            $lang = $r->lang!='nl'?'/' . $r->lang : '';
            $param = http_build_query(json_decode(stripslashes($r->filter_data), true));//json_decode($val, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            
            $url = site_url("/") . 'search-results/?' . $param . "&sid=" . $r->ID;
        ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $url;?>" class="place-view" data-id="<?php echo $r->ID;?>"><?php echo get_city($r->city_id)->name;?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
        
    <?php

}else{

    ?>
        <span class="no-item"><?php esc_html_e('No recent plan', 'golo-framework'); ?></span>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to reduce the number of characters in the title, ie the words?
Or the number of posts in the post

Comment: If you want to display more than 1 number of titles, you must set the value of posts_per_page equal to the value you want, for example 5 or 20

Comment: limit the number of posts shown, also i tried the post per page , but it keep giving allt he matching results

Comment: i tried  the post per page but it keep showing  all the results

Comment: Where did you define `$results`? It's not in your code snippet.

Comment: Why are there separate arrays for the `meta_query` instead of putting everything in your `$args_booking`? Also, you have `posts_per_page` set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of filters that run before WP_Query actually executes the desired SQL command, which means you posts_per_page setting can actually get overridden before your results are returned.

Unfortunately this can be done in both the theme you may be using, and in any plugins that maybe active. What I would do in this situation, is first check any of my other code to see if I am modifying the **pre_get_posts** or the **post_limits** filter.

I'd then check the theme settings to see if it has a setting for this, and last resort would be to disable plugins one by one to see if any of those are filtering the query.

Lastly don't discount cache being an issue. Some hosts can force caching of pages, even when you are logged in to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected this like this.
So you can take a pattern.
Let me know if it does not work or does
I used `posts_per_page` to set the number of posts per page (number of titles per page) Or you can use `numberposts`.
`numberposts` is used to search and display only 20 posts and `posts_per_page` is used to display 20 posts per page.

```
$args_booking = array(
    'post_type' => 'booking',
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'canceled'),
    'nopaging' => 'false',
    'posts_per_page' => 20, // for set limit.
    'orderby' => array(
        'menu_order' => 'ASC',
        'date' => 'DESC',
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => GOLO_METABOX_PREFIX . 'booking_item_author',
            'value' => $user_id,
            'type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'compare' => '=',
        )
    )
);


$query = new WP_Query($args_booking);
$results = $query->get_posts();


if (count($results) > 0) {//if( $total_post > 0 ){

    ?>

    <ul class="listing-detail custom-scrollbar">
        <?php foreach ($results as $r): ?>
            <?php
            $lang = $r->lang != 'nl' ? '/' . $r->lang : '';
            $param = http_build_query(json_decode(stripslashes($r->filter_data), true));//json_decode($val, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

            $url = site_url("/") . 'search-results/?' . $param . "&sid=" . $r->ID;
            ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="place-view"
                   data-id="<?php echo $r->ID; ?>">
                    <?php echo get_city($r->city_id)->name; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <?php

} else {

    ?>
    <span class="no-item"><?php esc_html_e('No recent plan', 'golo-framework'); ?></span>
    <?php
}
```